# How can I get matrices and text to show up in the same table with MatrixForm?

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, formatting, text-formatting

I'd like to be able to display matrices in the usual written MatrixForm in a table alongside text (or anything that isn't a matrix). Here is an example:

```
Clear[a, b, c, α, β, γ]; 
g = {{a^2, a*b*Cos[γ], a*c*Cos[β]}, {b*a*Cos[γ], b^2, b*c*Cos[α]}, {c*a*Cos[β], c*b*Cos[α], c^2}}; MatrixForm[g]
Clear[a, b, c, α, β, γ]; 
c = b = a; γ = β = α = 90*(Pi/180); g1…cubic = g; 
Clear[a, b, c, α, β, γ]; 
b = a; γ = β = α = 90*(Pi/180); g2…tetragonal = g; 
Clear[a, b, c, α, β, γ]; 
γ = β = α = 90*(Pi/180); g3…orthorhombic = g; 
Clear[a, b, c, α, β, γ]; 
b = a; β = α = 90*(Pi/180); γ = 120*(Pi/180); g4…hexagonal = g; 
Clear[a, b, c, α, β, γ]; 
γ = α = 90*(Pi/180); g5…monoclinic = g; 
Clear[a, b, c, α, β, γ]; 
c = b = a; γ = β = α; g6…rhombohedral = g; 
Clear[a, b, c, α, β, γ]; 
g7…triclinic = g; 
crystalsystemnames = {"Cubic", "Tetragonal", "Orthorhombic", "Hexagonal", "Monoclinic", "Rhombohedral", "Triclinic"}; 
metrictensors = Partition[{g1…cubic, g2…tetragonal, g3…orthorhombic, g4…hexagonal, g5…monoclinic, g6…rhombohedral, g7…triclinic}, 
    1]; 
data = MapThread[Append, {metrictensors, crystalsystemnames}]; 
MatrixForm[data, TableHeadings -> {None, {"Metric Tensor"}}]
```

This nearly produces the desired result, but the matrices within the table aren't displayed in Matrix Form:

[image]

This sounds like an easy fix, by just using MatrixForm earlier.

```
MatrixForm[metrictensors]
```

[image]

However, combining these methods doesn't work. This produces a MapThread error:

```
data = MapThread[Append, {MatrixForm[metrictensors], crystalsystemnames}]
```

I can display the matrices horizontally after which MapThread no longer computes:

```
Apply[MatrixForm, metrictensors, {1}]
```

ref/MatrixForm and ref/TableForm don't seem to have a combination example. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A simple approach is to use TraditionalForm, e.g., `MatrixForm[data, TableHeadings -> {None, {"Metric Tensor"}}] //TraditionalForm`

Answer (score 3):

```
crystalsystemnames = {"Cubic", "Tetragonal", "Orthorhombic", 
   "Hexagonal", "Monoclinic", "Rhombohedral", "Triclinic"};

metrictensors = Partition[{g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7}, 1];

data = MapThread[Append, {metrictensors, crystalsystemnames}];

MatrixForm[MapAt[MatrixForm, data, {All, 1}], TableHeadings -> {None, {"Metric Tensor"}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
data2 = MapThread[Append[{MatrixForm @ #}, #2] &, 
 {{g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7}, crystalsystemnames}];

MatrixForm[data2, TableHeadings -> {None, {"Metric Tensor"}}]
```

> ```
> same picture
> ```

**Note:** I replaced `gi...stuff` with `gi` in your code.